# Preparing to install Ubuntu two options (16.04.2)

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, system-installation, ssd

I'm dual booting Ubuntu with my already installed Windows 10. While installing Ubuntu I have this message where I can mark 1, 2 or non on these two options.

> Download updates while installing Ubuntu.
>
> Install third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware, Flash,
>   MP3 and other media

As a new user, what should I do in this step?

My **System** is: Dell XPS 15 9550

**Processor**: i7 6700HQ

**GPU**: GT-960M

**RAM**: 16GB DDR4

**Disk**: 512GB SSD (Samsung NVMe PM951)

**Thank You!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Download updates while installing" simply makes sure that everything is up-to-date when the install is finished. If you have a LAN or WiFi connection setup before starting the installation, it is a good idea to let it just download everything to make a clean and complete install.

If you decide not to take the extra time to download, it is no problem. You can easily do all of that in Software Update after rebooting following the installation.

The third party software is a bit "iffy" with some hardware - especially nVidia GPUs and some Wifi adapters. While it is generally no problem to install them, any problems with the third-party installation can stall or in very few cases, actually cause you to lose video or network connection... At any rate, with just a couple of devices to load drivers for... It can add significant wait time to your install. And, if your "Live Session" was problem-free, Ubuntu will boot just fine without them - giving you time to decide what you will need.

In my experience, it is generally better to wait until the system is installed and re-booted before installing the third party drivers... This too can be easily accomplished using the "Additional Drivers" selection in the "Control Panel". You will find it all the way at the bottom next to "firewall".

EDIT: As for your multiboot setup, Ubuntu setup will find Windows. And, when the Boot Loader (Grub2) is finished, There will be a nice entry in the menu for your windows installation... right below your brand new, shiny Ubuntu selection.
Make sure "fast boot" and/or "secure boot" are disabled in BIOS. And, make sure to disable "Hibernate" in Windows - as it will cause problems such as inability to boot back into Windows.
Welcome to Ubuntu.